# How to share resources between activities/services

Tags: android

I wanted to know what is the best approach for sharing singleton in my android app.
I have a few activities that does not rely on each other, but I want them to have a singleton that they can all read/write.

Where should I place it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your application should be a singleton. It avoids many other problem related to sharing datas or models.

In your manifest.xml :

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false"
    android:name="<class of your application see below>" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
 ..... all activities/services/receivers/etc... as usual

</application>
```

And your android:name refers to this class :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
//singleton, but use onCreate more than constructor to build shared resources.
....
}//class
```

And then, from within any activity, you can retrieve your singleton to get shared resources by doing this :

```
((MyApp)getApplicationContext()).getSharedResources()....
```

or

```
MyApp.getInstance().getSharedResources()....
```

Having a singleton as a app is a usual design pattern in android, it is especially useful to handle device rotation (as it tends to destroy activities and recreate them) as it provides a stable entity to persist during app lifecycle.

Comment: I believe `android:launchMode="singleTop"` isn't necessary since launchMode is an attribute of [activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode), not [application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html).